# Private beta "send as" tick boxes need better spacing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, private-beta

In the invite box, the 'send as' text is uncomfortably close to the tick boxes.

[image]

Could we add some more space?

Comment: Oh, hi, Myreal, nice to see you.

Comment: While we're being picky...it's also kind of silly when your display name matches your user name and then there's only one option that still has a radio button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed uncomfortably close! I pushed a fix for this to dev, will be on live server after our next production build.