# Tick boxes are too far from their text

Tags: bug, design

Text seems a little far away from its related tickbox as of late:

[image]

I'm willing to bet this was introduced while fixing [Private beta "send as" tick boxes need better spacing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248047/215468) - if it's intentional that's fine, I'll get used to it :)

Comment: There's just no pleasing you...

Comment: Don't care about the radio button distance, but that misaligned description text is terribad.

Comment: How close do they have to be? Readability-wise, that screenshot is decent

Comment: @random I think it's less about how close the header needs to be to the radial box, and more about the alignment of the header with the description text.

Comment: Those aren't tick boxes, which would be check boxes

Comment: Can you find a screenshot of how it was before? Personally I really can't see any problem here.

Answer (score 10):

I work at the pixel disposal unit here at Stack Exchange, and I've got to say, we're a little put off by this. First, do you know just *how many darn empty pixels we receive every day*? It's quadtrillions, easily - we just stop counting there.

*Someone* has got to do something with all of those empty pixels. We're a responsible company, so we don't do what other more evil companies do like send the pixels off to landfills, or bundle them up in heavy containers to be sunk into the ocean where they just leak out forever and pixelate coal reefs. We have to get rid of them *somehow*, so we work *really* hard to find places where a few extra pixels wouldn't really make a difference, and dispose of them that way, like scattering rock shavings out in the yard when you're breaking out of prison so the guards don't get wise.

I hate to do this, but I have to ask - given that you don't seem to appreciate the process that we go through, why do you hate the environment so much? C'mon man, we've all got to live here.

Comment: *Can't decide whether to upvote or downvote...*

Comment: You need to apply a green fill, so at least all those pixels and clean and green.

Comment: Hear, hear!  Pixel pollution is a major cause for ingrown toenails in the green tree frog of Borneo!!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Meuu.jpg