# Awesome new beta site design breaks user cards in flag queue

Tags: bug, flags, design, moderator-tools, user-card

I love the flat new design for beta sites. One thing I noticed: Usercards look different in the mod queue vs. the rest of the site:

[image: usercard in rest of site]

... vs. the mod queue version:

[image: usercard in mod queue]

I like having it more condensed, but it feels awkward having so little padding at the bottom.

Comment: Nobody puts baby in the corner...

Comment: blame [pixel disposal unit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248082/165773)